# How to modify index.html in runtime from Controller in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, controller, resources, runtime

I am working on a Spring Boot project which basically serving the UI from `resources/public`. When the request for the main page is arrived, I want to modify the `index.html` to add some data.

How can I do that?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that, the UI is written with AngularJS,HTML & SCSS if this changes anything. And I don't want to change variables, just want to add some data in `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a template engine such as Thymeleaf, Velocity, Freemarker...

In your Controller fill your model :

```
model.addAttribute("name", name);
```

In your Thymeleaf template :

```
<p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
```

Here's an example with Thymeleaf :
https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please take a look at my question again for edit part.